# To Fear or not to Fear that is the question

Tags: parashas-yisro, parshanut-torah-comment

The Posuk ([Exodus 20:17](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.17?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)) starts off:

וַיֹּאמֶר מֹשֶׁה אֶל-הָעָם אַל-תִּירָאוּ 

(And Moses said unto the people: ‘Don't fear' ...)

Then it goes on too say:

וּבַעֲבוּר תִּהְיֶה יִרְאָתוֹ עַל-פְּנֵיכֶם לְבִלְתִּי תֶחֱטָאוּ

(... and that His fear may be before you, that you don't sin)

The question is should we fear or not?

Comment: Why would you think fear of Hashem's Romemus, which keeps a person from sinning is similar to fear of humans, which is a lack of bitachon?

Comment: Its the same Posuk in the same sentence is hard to say he is switching subjects

Comment: Oops, my bad.  I was thinking that the first was from a different pasuk- which means I didn't even read your clearly stated question correctly!

Answer (score 2):

The **Shev Shematzah** in his Introduction to his work addresses this question. There where two things they where afraid of at Har Sinai. One was the Fireworks all around them the thunder and lightning, loud noises and Flames of fire from that Moshe was saying Do Not Be Afraid. Then there was Hashem who came down to deliver the Torah Fear of Heaven is diffrent there one should definitely be Afraid.